# Unable to use Makestyles from Material Ui

Tags: material-ui

So, I am using react with MUI (latest version), but the custom CSS is not working as in console. It is showing that.

> makestyles is no longer exported from `@mui/material/styles` ,instead try this `@mui/styles`

But after using it, it's raising an error which is.

> Failed to resolve import "@mui/styles" from "src\component\leaderboard.jsx". Does the file exist?

Here is my code.

```js
import React from 'react'
import Container from '@mui/material/Container'
import Button from '@mui/material/Button'
import {Grid} from '@mui/material'
import {Typography} from '@mui/material'
import {makeStyles} from '@mui/material/styles'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  btnLeader: {
    margin: '1rem',
  },
})

const Leaderboard = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <Container align='center'>
      <Typography
        variant='h4'
        align='center'
        fontFamily='revert-layer'
        color='black'
        gutterBottom>
        Leaderboard
      </Typography>
      <Grid
        container
        spacing='5m'
        justifyContent='center'>
        <Grid item>
          <Button
            variant='contained'
            className={classes.btnLeader}
            align='center'>
            Register
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant='outlined'
            align='center'>
            Top Gainers
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Leaderboard
```

Answer (score 1):

`makeStyle` is deprecated in MUI v5. Instead you can use `styled`, or the very easy to use `sx-prop`.

### [styled](https://mui.com/system/styled/#basic-usage)

```
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";

const StyledButton = styled(Button)({
  margin: "1rem",
});

export default function Test() {
  return <StyledButton variant="contained">styled button</StyledButton>;
}
```

### [sx-prop](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/#typescript-usage)

```
import { Button } from "@mui/material";

const classes = {
  btnLeader: {
    margin: "1rem",
  },
};

export default function Leaderboard() {
  return (
    <Button variant="contained" sx={classes.btnLeader}>
      sx prop button
    </Button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still encountering an error, make sure that you have installed the latest version of `@mui/styles` in your project. First try to run that.

With NPM

```
npm install @mui/styles
```

Or, with yarn

```
yarn add @mui/styles
```

Then try to use that.

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
```

Here is the official documentation:- [**MUI Material**](https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/). Please read this first for better understanding.

> The things are that `@mui/styles` is not compatible with `React.StrictMode` or React 18. And `@mui/styles` is the legacy styling solution for MUI. It depends on `JSS` as a styling solution, which is not used in the `@mui/material` any more, deprecated in v5.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using an outdated version of Material-UI. The makeStyles API has been moved to a new package @material-ui/styles in the latest version. Try installing and importing like that:

```
npm install @material-ui/styles
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
```

Also, make sure that the @material-ui/styles package is installed in your project and the import path is correct.